# Remove New Lines From String Without Removing "\n"?

Tags: python

I need data to train a bot, so I have scraped SO questions. How can I replace new lines without removing `\n` from strings?

If I have the following string:

```
"""You can use \n to print a new line.

Text text text."""
```

How can I get: `You can use \n to print a new line. Text text text.`

I've tried this: `string.replace("\n","")`

But I end up with: `'You can use  to print a new line.Text text text.'`

Since I'm dealing with programming questions, I'm destined to run into `\n` in a string and wouldn't want to replace that.

Comment: \n *are* newlines!

Comment: This doesn't really help me understand how to solve my problem.

Comment: Is that `\n` in `You can use \n to print a new line.`, literal or is that actually two lines of text?

Comment: Show an actual valid string, in quotes, I don't understand your aim at all

Comment: It's only one line.

Comment: In your example string, \n is a newline character, if you print it you will see a new line. (On certain OS setups \r also or \r\n acts as newline but this is not likely relevant here)

Comment: it doesn't make sense that `You can use \n to print a new line.` is only one line when printed because your code should have worked then. I hope you understand the difference between a literal newline character and an actual new line character. A literal newline looks like `\n` when printed. An actual newline will move the cursor to the next line. If your text contains literal newlines, then the code you have should work, otherwise you should redefine your goal as removing any instance of multiple newlines i.e. any part of your text that matches the regex `\n\n+`. Please clarify your goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could print it as a real string

this is done with the letter r

example 1:

```
print(r"You can use \n to print a new line.") 
# You can use \n to print a new line.
```

this will not remove it, but make it visible as you want in the output

example 2:

```
text = r"You can use \n to print a new line."

print(text) 
# You can use \n to print a new line.
```

Comment: This might be a better option than my answer :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the issue of replacing the newlines in the string...

Answer (score 2):

If you are printing the string and the output is:

```
You can use \n to print a new line.

Text text text.
```

then the `\n` visible in the output is actually the backslash character followed by the letter `n`, and not a newline character.

Doing `replace("\n", "")` should not remove the sequence of characters `\n`, because the replace pattern `"\n"` itself is not the sequence of characters `\n`, but rather the actual single newline character. So it does not match the `\n` sequence of characters visible in your string, but it does match (and replace) the newline characters.

This REPL snippet illustrates that:

```
>>> x = """You can use \\n to print a new line.\n\nText text text.""" # this string literal is how you would create the string you have shown in you question.
>>> x == r"""You can use \n to print a new line.
... 
... Text text text.""" # or you can use a raw string literal to initialize your variable, it is exactly the same thing
True
>>> print(x)
You can use \n to print a new line.

Text text text.
>>> print(x.replace("\n", ""))
You can use \n to print a new line.Text text text.
```

If you mean that you are creating a string with the literal:

```
"""You can use \n to print a new line.

Text text text."""
```

Then it is impossible to distinguish between the typed `\n` and the result of pressing the `Enter` key in your string literal (unless you use a raw string initializer, as other answers have explained). Once the code is interpreted by Python they are identical. Consider escaping the newline character in your literal to have it included in your string as is:

```
myString = """You can use \\n to print a new line.

Text text text."""
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert new lines to literal string `\n`, you can escape the slash character:

`string.replace("\n","\\n")`

Comment: This would result in `You can use \n to print a new line.\n\nText text text.` which does not seem to be what the OP wants. Then again, the question does not make any sense...

Comment: @zr0gravity7 Yes, the question is not very clear. Seems like another answer worked for OP.

Answer (score 1):

The `\n` in your string is an escape sequence that gets evaluated to the newline character.

```py
In [1]: s = """You can use \n to print a new line.
   ...:
   ...: Text text text."""

In [2]: print(s)
You can use
 to print a new line.

Text text text.
```

If you want to actually include the characters `\` and `n` in your string, you need to escape the backslash with another backslash.

```py
In [3]: s = """You can use \\n to print a new line.
   ...:
   ...: Text text text."""

In [4]: print(s)
You can use \n to print a new line.

Text text text.

In [5]: print(s.replace("\n", ""))
You can use \n to print a new line.Text text text.
```

Alternatively, you could use a "raw string", i.e. a string prefixed with `r`, e.g. `r"..."` or `r"""..."""` but then you would no longer be able to use escape sequences such as `\n` to insert a newline character, `\t` to insert a tab, etc.